# Model is not generating weights with auto-generate, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: rigging, bones

I am attempting to import a model using the MMD plugin and then use it for animation. When I import the model, give it bones, and then attempt to animate it, the bones are not affecting the model.

What am I doing wrong? I can provide more details as needed.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all for the automatic weighting to work (which is never guaranteed by the way) each bones should be inside the mesh. Your hands here are problematic, you want to place the hands bones inside the hands mesh. This could fix it.

Comment: It did not, this was just an example screenshot. Even when the bones are entirely within the mesh, the auto-weighting does nothing.

Comment: I think you could select the mesh and clean all vertex groups. Select it again then the armature and make a parent again. Another thing I was thinking about: This could be an issue caused by the unsupported characters. Eg: a lot of squares_mesh_a lot of squares.